# How to install Xsendfile

Tags: php, server, installation

I want to install Xsendfile on my linux server but not *quite* sure exactly how to do it. I'm following this guide:

https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

But not quite sure how to download the file exactly with ssh. I mean how do I initiate a download and once downloaded where will it be? To be honest the rest is probably straight forward, its just that part I'm stuck on.

Comment: You might have better luck posting this on https://serverfault.com

Comment: Which flavour are you running?

Answer (score 8):

If running Ubuntu and Apache2 you can install like so:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-xsendfile
```

and enable it with:

```
sudo a2enmod xsendfile
```

You'll also need to configure you VirtualHost

Comment: That first line didn't seem to work. It said 'apt-get: command not found'.

Comment: Because you're not running a Debian based system. You should be clearer in your question.

Comment: e2enmod => a2enmod (not needed anyway)

Comment: About the e2enmod typo: “Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?” – StackOverflow, are you kidding?

Answer (score 1):

To get the source, you can use:

```
wget https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/mod_xsendfile-0.12.tar.gz
```

Then use:

```
tar xzf mod_xsendfile-0.12.tar.gz
```

To uncompress it.

From there, follow the instructions on the page.

Comment: Ok I did that and it went through ok but then I tried to follow the instructions on that page which the next step would be:

apxs -cia mod_xsendfile.c

but that just said not found. Do I need to change it to

apxs -cia mod_xsendfile-0.12

?  Well it seems no because that didn't work either. It said 'cannot determine bootstrap name'. Any ideas?

Comment: This means you need to install the Apache development modules as well. apxs compiles Apache modules and is only included with the apache devel package.